# Error when export mysql to csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

novice here, I created the following query to select from database and export as csv, but I keep getting an error:

```
$query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,email WHERE firstname = 'Trenton' INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tjtest2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM students";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('error'); 
if($result)
{
    echo"yes!";
}
else
{
    echo"NO!";
};
```

my dreaded die error keeps coming up and I can't figure out where the issue is

Comment: I have been trying to troubleshoot.  It seems when I just do the select part of the code, I do not get the error.  The error is with "INTO OUTFILE" and I don't understand why:

Comment: (THIS WORKS ... )$query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,email FROM students WHERE firstname = 'Trenton' "; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('error'); 
if($result){echo"yes!";}else{echo"NO!";};

Comment: What am I doing wrong with the part "INTO OUTFILE" ?

Comment: OKAY - I used my query on a local version and it did it just fine.  Apparenty the query itself is correct (the latest one from below, that is) That means there is something up with my hosting.  I made sure my user had all privileges, and still no luck.  I read in the documentation that I have to have 'file privilege', when I looked at my user privileges I don't see a checkbox for 'file' privilege.  (I use hostgator)  Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Mate, there's no such thing as `C:/` in a hosted environment. That's why it works on your local machine but not with Hostgator. Your `OUTFILE` must match your allowed path on their server.

Comment: Thank you, I feel silly for not catching that.

Comment: Okay - I tried my code with the correct directory and same problem ..

Comment: $query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,email FROM students WHERE firstname = 'Trenton' INTO OUTFILE '/csv/tjtest2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('error 4');
if($result){echo"yes!";}else{echo"still no";};

Answer (score 0):

You need to user from students before where condition

```
$query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,email form students WHERE firstname = 'Trenton' INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tjtest2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

Comment: $query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,email FROM students WHERE firstname = 'Trenton' INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tjtest2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('error'); 
if($result){echo"yes!";}else{echo"NO!";};

Comment: your welcome , please mark correct answer if it help you :)

Comment: and I am still getting the die error - anything else I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You are placing where condition at wrong place, so use code as per below-

```
$query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,email INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tjtest2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM students WHERE firstname = 'Trenton'";
```

**Update:**

Get directory path where your mysql can write by below command-

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';
```

It will provide you a path like "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Uploads\", so use this path as per below-

```
$query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,email INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/Uploads/tjtest2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM students WHERE firstname = 'Trenton'";
```

Comment: Thank you I tried your suggestion and I am still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: check my update and if still getting error then share exact error....even first just execute sql statement from any tool like sqlyog etc and share error provided by mysql.

Comment: Thank you, I tried  "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';" in the mysql field of myphpadmin and it did not give me the answer.  Obviously I don't know how to implement your "show variables" suggestion.  How do I implement it?  btw - I also checked my error logs and all it will say is "syntax error, unexpected 'INTO' (T_STRING)" which is odd because the exact same wording works just fine on my local machine

Comment: you can ask your dba or who have required privileges to get this path. actually mysql can write where mysql have rights...and you can write on this path without any extra permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your error logs to get the exact error? Can it be that the file already exists? You can also try `mysql_error()` inside of your else part, remember to remove `or die` when testing that, to see if you find some details on what is going wrong

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I tried to implement it:

Comment: $query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,email FROM students WHERE firstname = 'Trenton' INTO OUTFILE '/csv/tjtest2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result){echo"yes!";}else{mysql_error($query);};

Comment: and I get this:  "Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in"...    so obviously I implemented it wrong?

Comment: Try mysql_error() without $query or any other parameter, the optional parameter is to identify the connection if you have several connections

Comment: I tried your suggestion and finally got the error message: "Access denied for user '.... etc. "  So I decided my database connecting query was bad.  I then performed another query where I simply selected data from the table and it worked just fine - so I know that my user DOES have access.  Why would my user have access to select from a table but not to export csv into outfile?

Comment: The access denied is probably for writing the file, not selecting the data. Have you tried exporting it to temp directory instead to see if you have write access there?

Answer (score 0):

Okay folks, I have learned that there is nothing wrong with my query afterall.  The problem is my webhost does not provide sharers with high enough privileges to allow me to implement "INTO OUTFILE".  For those who DO have high enough privileges, apparently this query should work:

```
$query = "SELECT record FROM table WHERE variable INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
echo"yes!";
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
};
```